# how to select a button in highcharts-range selector row and click

Tags: python-3.x, highcharts, range

I am trying to get data from the following page. However, I would like to check if the range All is selected before getting the data. I am unable to get this because the highcharts element XPATH keeps changing.

The page is

http://www.4-traders.com/APPLE-4849/charts-historical/

How do I select the element and click on it so that I can get all the data.

I am using python and selenium (Chrome Driver)
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this before you download the data. This will loop through the buttons available in highchart and click on it when 'All' text is found.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".highcharts-button-box")
for button in buttons:
    if button.text == 'All':
        button.click()
        break
#code to download data
```

Comment: I tried it but get an error "'WebElement' object is not iterable". Also if I use buttons[9].click() errors is "WebElement object does not support indexing"

Comment: Sorry worked. I think it should be find_elements_by_css_selector.